# How to implement and show fullcalendar events into boostrap modal

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, frontend, bootstrap-modal

I am implementing a calendar for my new website
I retrieve events from a BackEnd application and show result in a modal using fullcalendar.
Everything works fine, but when I open and display the modal/the calendar, the events are not rendered on the calendar until I press next or prev button.

I already tried to render the calendar, rerender, next or prev programmatically.

Here is my code for the calendar, 
Of course 'calendar-results' is a modal-body of a modal dialog

```
var calendarResultsEl = document.getElementById('calendar-results');
calendarResults = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarResultsEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction','timeGrid', 'list'],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    slotDuration:'01:00:00',
    scrollTime : '08:00:00',
    firstDay: 1, 
    height:'parent',
    handleWindwoResize:true,
    header: {
        left:   '',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'today prev,next'
    },
        events: elements,
    eventMouseEnter : function(info)
    {
        var element = info.el;
        element.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');
        element.setAttribute('data-container', 'body');
        element.setAttribute('data-rel', 'popover')
        element.setAttribute('data-trigger', 'hover');
        element.setAttribute('data-content', "<font size='3'><b>Start :</b>" + info.event.start + "<br>" + "<b>End :</b>" + info.event.end + "<br></font>");
        element.setAttribute('data-placement', 'top');
        element.setAttribute('data-title', "<font size='6'>" + info.event.id + "</font>");
        $(function () { 
            $("[data-rel=popover]").popover();   
        });
    },
    columnHeaderFormat:{
        weekday:'long',
        day:'numeric',
        month:'long'
    },
    eventClick : function(info){
        $("#startTime").val(moment.utc(info.event.start));
        $("#endTime").val(moment.utc(info.event.end));
        $("#name").val(info.event.title);
        $("#eventInfo").html(info.event.description);
        $("#eventLink").attr('href', info.event.url);
        $("#eventContent").modal('show');
    }
});
calendarResults.render();
```

Here are my events object :

```
[
  {
    "end": "2019-03-11T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 0,
    "start": "2019-03-11T04:32:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2019-03-12T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2019-03-12T04:32:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2019-03-13T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2019-03-13T04:32:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2019-03-14T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 3,
    "start": "2019-03-14T04:32:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2019-03-15T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 4,
    "start": "2019-03-15T04:32:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2019-03-18T19:02:00.000Z",
    "id": 5,
    "start": "2019-03-18T04:32:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Of course the problem won't appear with this event object,
I made a jsFiddle to show my problem.
The events for the current week don't appear unless you press prev/next. 
Also, changing the size of the result window show the events.

https://jsfiddle.net/Marech/2Lqgewdc/7/

Anyone has succeed to show a calendar into a boostrap modal ?
Maybe I should check for the events triggered when button are pressed and do the same thing programmatically after calendar rendering. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button code you can manually force a window resize event:

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {

  modal.style.display = "block";
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

}
```

This works, but this way of working with modals; directly manipulating styles, is not the most elegant way.  You should consider reviewing Bootstrap's modal documentation, or at least use a library to handle modal functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I tried and it does work althought as you said it is not so elegant to open modals this way. 
I will edit my fiddle with the proper way of defining a boostrap modal.

Comment: I also vaguely remember certain issues with content inside modals, because some plugins like calendars etc, expect that the content is visible before they're initialized.  The resize hack may indeed be the simplest way to get this done for now.